# How to customize multipanel BarCharts (e.g., ChartLayout -> "Row")?

Tags: plotting, bugs, labeling, time-series

**Bug introduced in 13.0**

---

In version `13.0.0` support for multipanel plots has been added to 15 visualization functions —among them `BarChart`. I would like to use `ChartLayout -> "Row"` to display a couple of time series using `BarChart`.

Let's quickly set up some data and look at a simple example.

```
ts = TimeSeries[ { 110, 220, 150, 330 }, { 2020, 2023, 1 } ];
td = TemporalData[ { ts, ts, ts } ];

BarChart[ 
    td
  , ChartLabels ->  { {"A", "B", "C"} , td["Times"] }
  , ChartStyle -> Blue
]
```

[image: Figure1]

Let's try this with a multipanel plot:

```
BarChart[
    td 
  , ChartLayout -> "Row"
  , ChartLabels -> { {"A", "B", "C"} , td["Times"] }
  , ChartStyle -> Blue
]
```

[image: Figure2]

That's not quite what I wanted. The color can be added using `ColorFunction` and using "brute force" with replacement rules we can add the labels.

```
BarChart[
    td 
  , ChartLayout -> "Row"
  , ChartLabels -> { {"A", "B", "C"} , td["Times"] }
  , ColorFunction -> ( Blue & )
] /. Text[ x_Integer, r__ ] /; 1 <= x <= 4 :> Text[ 2019 + x, r ]
```

[image: Figure3]

It seems that `ChartLayout -> "Row"` and other multipanel layouts take precedence over other options, which unfortunately seems to be undocumented. For example, `ChartElementFunction` and certain wrappers like `Labeled` seem to be rendered ineffective.

Are there more elegant and regular ways to customize multipanel plots?

---

Wolfram Technical Support: **[CASE:4933331]**

Comment: Wolfram Technical Support just confirmed that "_the ChartLayout option is unexpectedly interfering with other options in Histogram, BarChart, and other related functions._" The issue will (hopefully) be fixed in an upcoming release.